# what is the easiest way to bind data to 30 dropdownlists?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

my question is very simple. here is my scenario:

1. i have 1 result dataset[named="resultDS" typed="MyDataset"] and 1 datatable[MyDT] inside.
2. in datatable, i have 10 rows, each row has 3 columns [Column1,Column2,Column3]
3. on aspx page, i have 30 drowdownlists waiting for above data

The data inside dataTable will be:

Column1  |   Column2   |    Column3

Method1  |      100    |       0.5

Method2  |      125    |       0.75

Method3  |      80     |      0.4

.
.
.

Method30  |     200    |      1

currently, i used the simplest way for binding data. something like:

```
ddl1.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[0]).Column1;
ddl2.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[0]).Column2;
ddl3.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[0]).Column3;

ddl4.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[1]).Column1;
ddl5.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[1]).Column2;
ddl6.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[1]).Column3;
.
.
.
ddl30.SelectedValue = ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[9]).Column3;
```

Is there any way to bind data to my ddl easier than my current method?

Thank you.

vcha

Comment: With out knowing more about your datatable and ddls I dont think so.
If your 30 ddls are actually 3 ddls' repeated 10 times then you could use a repeater or listview.

Comment: Whey is ddl2 repated twice but not other ddls ?

Comment: Now 3 is repeated but I get that sequence but in the last line shouldn't it be Row[9] and not Row[29] ? (just trying to figure out the pattern)

Comment: Thank you both Bala R and Chad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the last line in you code has `Rows[9]`

You can try doing it in a loop

```
for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) FindControl("ddl"+(i+1));

   switch (i % 3)
   {
      case 0:
          ddl.SelectedValue =  ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[i/3]).Column1;
          break;
      case 1:
          ddl.SelectedValue =  ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[i/3]).Column2;
          break;
      case 2:
          ddl.SelectedValue =  ((MyDataSet.MyDTRow)resultDS.MyDT.Rows[i/3]).Column3;
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bala R. This is what i want but dont know how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would set this up in a Databound control Like a `ListView` or `GridView`.

This will allow you to Create the 3 ddls that will be repeated then bind the `SelectedItemValue` to your column.

I am making some assumptions based on what you have shown that this will work for you.  If the ddls are scattered throughout the site then it may not.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The reason i have to use ddl is because the UI designer has design them and put them inside table surrounded by graphic object. so i cannot change the type of control.

Comment: Actually a gridview renders as a table in html. You can also set the listview up in table form.  If you style the table with css the control should just drop right in perfectly